# Is my orbital sander fixable?

Tags: sanding, tool-maintenance, tool-repair

[previously asked in Home Improvement, perhaps better here?]

I have a Bosch PSS230 orbital sander (1990's vintage I think) which has served me very well until recently when it made a nasty noise and some whitish-grey powdery lumps dropped out of the bottom. Having had a look at it it looks like the lumps were the remnants of some sort of cement/rubber 'linkage' between the spindle and the eccentric cam outer bit, from the gap indicated by the red arrow marked on the image.

[image]

Just wondering if anyone here has had a similar problem, and whether there is a suitable material (silicone, acrylic...) with which I can rebuild it?

Comment: The Lumps were probably just old sawdust impacted in the machine. Hard to be sure without seeing, but it doesn't sound like something I'd worry about; it may be an improvement.

Comment: Thanks keshlam. I had a sneaking suspicion that might be the case. I've just tried it out again, and without the plate that takes the sandpaper attached (i.e. how it is in the photo), it seems to run OK. But as soon as I put the plate back on it just buzzes and moves feebly. The silver bit with the eccentric 'cam' on seem to be driven directly by the motor, whereas the central bit with the three screw holes for the plate, slips. So I originally assumed that there had been something between the two to provide a flexible drive. Maybe not? Hmm.

Comment: Just encase you do not find out, if the problem is still about I put a little more thought not my answer, check it out.

Comment: I've sorted this out now, and in case I mislead anyone else with this, there was NOT a broken down flexible linkage in there, it was just compacted sawdust as some have suggested. The problem was just a sticky bearing which I've now freed up and all is good.

Answer (score 1):

I am going to completely redo my answer for I have a much better Idea (Had to do some cleaning with belt sander). But I still am going to say that it is wood dust and does need to be taken care of. But (of course, not sure how far you could go) if you can remove a side or the bottom and take a look inside that may help out with cleaning. If there was a 'rubber/ceramic' thing then dust can travel up there. Can reduce performance, increase wear/tear (depending on what it is on...), and increase heat buildup. If there is dust on the inside clean it out but prefer not to get it wet for that may do wonders. Another thing to look at is the carbon brush on the sides (of any). They do where over time and is very important to replace these. Not doing so will be VERY bad (at least worn down). Last thing to think of is with the sealing. I would not use a silicone, for I can see that hardening on the moving part. Which will either give loose and work or hang on but separate from the whole bottom. What I was thinking was using foam. Like for doors that has some stick on one side (can not think of the name). If done right that should work better I hope. Otherwise ask some questions, my knowledge on some of this has improved but like I said, no expert of any. Note: If you do take it apart that is your choice. I do not want to be blamed for anything, thank you.